# How can I parse just a section of big log based on datetime in python

Tags: python, file, datetime, parsing, logging

I wanted to parse just a section of any given log. I just need to start from start_time of my log and end at end_time of my code.
The datetime format is "[2021-09-14 21:56:01.768]"
So basically suppose I needed to start from "[2021-09-14 21:56:01.768]" part of log and end at "[2021-09-14 21:58:56.608]" and need to parse content between these two, parsing the content I have already written, but not understanding how to take this time section from code.

Sample log:

```
[2021-11-19 11:27:23.169] (Info)    (001473039)(2:0): AdminCmdIdentify CNS=0x00 CNTID=00 NSID=0001 FID=00^M
[2021-11-19 11:27:23.169] (Info)    (001473039)(2:0): Host_TransferAdminData: [FWCMD_A:8018] [HWCMD_A:8800] pBuffer:0x7FF02000 xferCount:0x1000 autoFreeBuffer:1 handlerFptr:0x0 direction:0 ^M
[2021-11-19 11:27:23.169] (Info)    (001473039)(2:0): AdminCmdIdentify CNS=0x00 CNTID=00 NSID=0001 FID=00^M
[2021-11-19 11:27:23.169] (Info)    (001473039)(2:0): Host_TransferAdminData: [FWCMD_A:8019] [HWCMD_A:8800] pBuffer:0x7FF02000 xferCount:0x1000 autoFreeBuffer:1 handlerFptr:0x0 direction:0 ^M
[2021-11-19 11:27:23.169] (Info)    (001473039)(2:0): AdminCmdIdentify CNS=0x01 CNTID=00 NSID=0000 FID=00^M
[2021-11-19 11:27:23.169] (Info)    (001473039)(2:0): Host_TransferAdminData: [FWCMD_A:801A] [HWCMD_A:8800] pBuffer:0x7FF02000 xferCount:0x1000 autoFreeBuffer:1 handlerFptr:0x0 direction:0 ^M
```

Comment: can you provide a couple of lines of your log? What have you tried so far

Comment: @nikeros parsing the content I got, but how to take just a section I am not getting a start idea.

Comment: @nikeros shared in question part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method below takes the start and end date along with the string logs and returns the logs in between two dates.

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

def get_interval_logs(start_time, end_time, logs):
    processed_logs = []
    pattern = re.compile(r'([[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3})](.+)')
    for (time, content) in re.findall(pattern, logs):
        log_time = datetime.strptime(time,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        if start_time < log_time and log_time < end_time:
            processed_logs.append(content)
    return "\n".join(processed_logs) 

logs="""[2021-11-19 11:27:23.169] (Info)    (001473039)(2:0): AdminCmdIdentify CNS=0x00 CNTID=00 NSID=0001 FID=00^M
[2021-11-20 11:27:23.169] (Info)    (001473039)(2:0): Host_TransferAdminData: [FWCMD_A:8018] [HWCMD_A:8800] pBuffer:0x7FF02000 xferCount:0x1000 autoFreeBuffer:1 handlerFptr:0x0 direction:0 ^M
[2021-11-21 11:27:23.169] (Info)    (001473039)(2:0): AdminCmdIdentify CNS=0x00 CNTID=00 NSID=0001 FID=00^M
[2021-11-22 11:27:23.169] (Info)    (001473039)(2:0): Host_TransferAdminData: [FWCMD_A:8019] [HWCMD_A:8800] pBuffer:0x7FF02000 xferCount:0x1000 autoFreeBuffer:1 handlerFptr:0x0 direction:0 ^M
[2021-11-23 11:27:23.169] (Info)    (001473039)(2:0): AdminCmdIdentify CNS=0x01 CNTID=00 NSID=0000 FID=00^M
[2021-11-24 11:27:23.169] (Info)    (001473039)(2:0): Host_TransferAdminData: [FWCMD_A:801A] [HWCMD_A:8800] pBuffer:0x7FF02000 xferCount:0x1000 autoFreeBuffer:1 handlerFptr:0x0 direction:0 ^M"""

start_time = datetime(2021,11,20)
end_time = datetime(2021,11,23)
print(get_interval_logs(start_time, end_time, logs))
```

It will print out:

```
 (Info)    (001473039)(2:0): Host_TransferAdminData: [FWCMD_A:8018] [HWCMD_A:8800] pBuffer:0x7FF02000 xferCount:0x1000 autoFreeBuffer:1 handlerFptr:0x0 direction:0 ^M
 (Info)    (001473039)(2:0): AdminCmdIdentify CNS=0x00 CNTID=00 NSID=0001 FID=00^M
 (Info)    (001473039)(2:0): Host_TransferAdminData: [FWCMD_A:8019] [HWCMD_A:8800] pBuffer:0x7FF02000 xferCount:0x1000 autoFreeBuffer:1 handlerFptr:0x0 direction:0 ^M
```